# The Unicode bell character is not working in my code

Tags: javascript, unicode

Could someone tell me why the JavaScript Unicode bell is not working for me?
My JS code:

```js
console.log("\u0007")
```

Google Chrome's console is showing this --> [image]

My full code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script>console.log("\u0007")</script>
<h1 style="background-color: red;">Hello World!</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Thank you.

Comment: What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: I want to hear the system bell ringing...

Comment: I'd be really surprised if that works in a browser, the console will just be rendering the passed string.